# Coordinate geometry basic

Tags: analytic-geometry

Two straight lines l and m pass through the point (1,1). Slope of line l passing through the point (0,a) is less than the slope of the line m that passes through the point(0,b).

- Quantity A : a
- Quantity B : b

Options:

- Quantity A is greater than Quantity B
- Quantity B is greater than Quantity A
- Quantity A is equal to Quantity B
- Relationship cannot be determined

If I have envisioned this properly, the figure looks something like this:

[image: Figure]

I think answer should be B, but it is given as A 
ie, a>b how is that possible?

Comment: In your image, the line going through $(0,b)$ has slope less than the line going through $(0,a)$.

Comment: @A.Goodier because slope is of negative value, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the two point form for both lines,

$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

Equation for the lines are:

$y=(1-a)x + a$ for line $l$

$y=(1-b)x + b$ for line $m$

Slope of line $l$ is less than that of $m$:

$1-a < 1-b$

$a > b$

Comment: Better approach, Thanks! :)